# Proving that the hyperbinary representation of $2n+1$ equals that of $n$.

Tags: number-theory

I am reading this paper: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/recounting.pd. It proves the equality of the hyperbinary representations of $2n+1$ and $n$ as follows:

[image]

Now, when it states "the "1" must appear", does it mean in the hyperbinary representation of $2n+1$? And if so, how would "subtracting 1 from both sides and dividing by 2" possibly give a hyperbinary representation equal to that of $n$, when $2n$ has at least one less hyperbinary representation than $2n+1$?

Sorry if I'm missing something blatantly evident.

(Note: The hyperbinary representation of $n$  is the number of ways in which it can be written as sums of powers of two, where each power of two can occur at most twice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any binary representation of $2n+1$, we must have the zeroth power of 2 appearing (because the number $2n+1$ is odd). It can't possibly have another 1 in its binary representation, because that would use up all the 1's we're allowed (that is, all two of them), leaving an odd number to be made as a sum of (even) powers of 2.

Therefore, any odd number has precisely one $2^0$ in any hyperbinary-eligible representation.

Now, the hyperbinary-eligible representation of the rest of the number is precisely determined by the $2^1, 2^2, \dots$ terms. Can we think of another number which is precisely determined by those terms? Yes: subtract one from the original and divide by 2, to obtain another number $n$. The hyperbinary-eligible representations of $n$ can all be turned into hyperbinary-eligible representations of $2n+1$ by means of "increase every power of 2 by 1, and add in $2^0$".